# cvCreateFileCapture() unable to read h 264 encoded mp4 file

Tags: opencv, video, h.264, decoder

I have the following piece of code in opencv to read an mp4 file:

```
    CvCapture *capture =cvCreateFileCapture("DemoRecording.mp4");
    if(!capture){
        cout<<endl<<"Capture from file error"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    CvSize sz =cvSize((int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
    CvVideoWriter *writer =cvCreateVideoWriter("DemoRecording.avi", CV_FOURCC('L','A','G','S'), (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS), sz);
    IplImage *frame =cvCreateImage(sz, 8, 3);
    while(1){
        // Read Frames  
    }
    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

However, I am unable to read the mp4 file. This file is encoded using H. 264. I have the following details of the file displayed by ffmpeg:

```
fplay version N-42347-g299387e Copyright (c) 2003-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul  8 2012 15:44:54 with gcc 4.7.1
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libcelt --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libutvideo --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      51. 64.100 / 51. 64.100
  libavcodec     54. 33.100 / 54. 33.100
  libavformat    54. 15.102 / 54. 15.102
  libavdevice    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
  libavfilter     3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'DemoRecording.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf53.31.100
  Duration: 00:00:16.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 819 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 540x720, 816 kb/s, 21.19 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Frame changed from size:0x0 to size:540x720
[ffplay_buffer @ 04149040] w:540 h:720 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/600 fr:0/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:
[ffplay_buffersink @ 04ca69c0] No opaque field provided
```

I have the updated k-lite codec pack installed on my machine. I have ffmpeg as well. Softwares like premiere pro which use libavcodec vfw for decoding mp4 files are able to playback the file.

However, openCV isn't able to read the file. Any help on this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you successfully access other video files?

Comment: I am able to read avi files successfully (encoded by Lagarith). With H 264 encoded mp4 files, no luck.

Comment: Copy the latest opencv_ffmpeg.dll (or opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll for x64) locally in your executable. You can find it inside the opencv zip file (3rdparty\ffmpeg). Version 2.4.6 is out.

Comment: Did that. still no luck. Btw would that make a difference?

Comment: In case the system was reading an older version, yes. Do you have time to debug? Copy cap.cpp into your project and any header it asks. Then, add any files needed to debug further. All you need is in opencv/modules/highgui/src. Also, better use the opencv 2 standard (VideoCapture). Oh, I forgot to ask: does opencv print any warning or error?

Comment: Probably you might be correct regarding an older version of ffmpeg since I had various versions of ffmpeg sitting in the system. Anyways, I will try it out on a different machine as well. Meanwhile, I will try and debug.

Comment: I am having problems in linking. I have linked opencv_highgui244.lib and opencv_highgui244d.lib as well. There are still unresolved externals. Can you please specify the libs I should link ?

Comment: Search INSIDE the files of opencv\modules\* for the missing functions and then insert either the source file if you want to debug it or the respective lib. Please, post a function missing and I'll give you an example.

Comment: As an example, 
1>cap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct CvCapture * __cdecl cvCreateCameraCapture_VFW(int)" (?cvCreateCameraCapture_VFW@@YAPAUCvCapture@@H@Z)

Comment: What if you copy into your project file `cap_vfw.cpp`? `cvCreateCameraCapture_VFW` is gone but more showed?

Comment: That doesn't help either. cap_vfw.cpp shows up "1>cap_vfw.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ICSendMessage@16" link error and I cannot find _ICSendMessage either.

Comment: Go 2 step backwards and remove both cap.cpp and cap_vfw.cpp from your project. Now, insert /highgui/src/precomp.hpp into your project and include it in stdafx.h. Works? (Re-build all.)

Comment: Yes. It does compile and build fine.

Comment: What if you insert cap.cpp now? The same?

Comment: Yes. Its still the same.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that we pasted a cross-platform file into your project. Some `#define` are excluding parts of code from being compiled. So, I don't know how exactly, but you must keep only the code you are using based on your platform. Good luck. (or insert the whole library in the project and find these defines...this will take some time too!) Can't help you anymore from here.